# Freemarker with spring mvc, so what will my action look like?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, freemarker

In my `appname-servlet.xml` I have:

```
<!-- freemarker config -->
<bean id="freemarkerConfig" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.freemarker.FreeMarkerConfigurer">
  <property name="templateLoaderPath" value="/WEB-INF/freemarker/"/>
</bean>

<!-- 

  View resolvers can also be configured with ResourceBundles or XML files. If you need
  different view resolving based on Locale, you have to use the resource bundle resolver.

-->
<bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.freemarker.FreeMarkerViewResolver">
  <property name="cache" value="true"/>
  <property name="prefix" value=""/>
  <property name="suffix" value=".ftl"/>

  <!-- if you want to use the Spring FreeMarker macros, set this property to true -->
  <property name="exposeSpringMacroHelpers" value="true"/>

</bean>
```

So I have my `HomeController.java`'s index view at: `/web-inf/freemarker/index.ftl`

I am hoping someone can create a dead simple Index action that will create a `ModelAndView` and use `freemarker`.

I'm not sure how things will wire together, thanks!

Comment: What do you mean, "index action"? If you already have `HomeController`, what else do you need?

Comment: I'm lost, how do I setup the freemarker object etc?  Yes I have a HomeController, and a Index action.  I need help setting up freemarker from within the action and returning the view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The controllers should have no knowledge of Freemarker, they should just look like any other controller, constructing the `ModelAndView` or `ModelMap` as they normally would. The `FreeMarkerViewResolver` takes the view name held in the `ModelAndView` and resolves it to a Freemarker `Template` object internally, rendering your model into that. All freemarker config is internal to the `FreeMarkerViewResolver`

If your context is not wired up correctly, then the `FreeMarkerViewResolver` will throw an exception to that effect, but you certainly do not require any freemarker config in your controllers.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need freemarkerConfig, I think. Just change your view resolver a bit:

```
<bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.freemarker.FreeMarkerViewResolver">
    <property name="cache" value="true"/>
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/freemarker/"/>
    <property name="suffix" value=".ftl"/>
    <property name="exposeSpringMacroHelpers" value="true"/>
</bean>
```

Now if you open hppt://localhost:8080/app/index, you will get rendered /WEB-INF/freemarker/index.ftl